# What does 'as favorable to' mean?

Tags: comparisons

What's the meaning of this comparison:

> One can compare Makan's quality of life as favorable to that of most other peasants in regions.

So was Makan's quality of life the same, slightly better, or much better than the most other peasants?

Comment: The construction is not really "as favorable to".  Here you need to understand the combination "compare ... to ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is sure, is that Makan's quality of life can be considered ***better*** than that of most other peasants. We can rewrite your sentence in this way:

> Compared to the quality of life of most other peasants in regions,
> that (*the quality of life*) of Makan can be considered as (being) favourable.

***How much better*** it is, is determined by ***favourable***. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favourable) defines it as:

> giving you an advantage or more chance of success:
>
> - favourable weather conditions

"Favourable" is not an [Uncomparable adjective](https://thebettereditor.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/the-incomparable-adjective/#:%7E:text=something%20that%27s%20unequaled%20or%20matchless,it%20describes%20an%20absolute%20condition.) like ***irrevocable*** or ***dead*** can be. Therefore it has a positive connotation, but has degrees (more, less, (the) most (the) least). None of these were used, only the plain ***favourable*** was given in the sentence.

This determines me to say that Makan's quality of life was neither *slightly better* nor  *much better* than that of most other peasants, but it was ***somewhat/significantly better***. (Note that ***significantly*** is a higher degree than ***somewhat***, it means "in  a noticeably or measurably large amount" [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/significant), but it is less than ***much better***).

Answer (score 0):

The degree of improved quality of life is not directly described.
It is however implied as Makan remains a peasant.
Therefore one can assume that the quality of life was slight, but not great enough to rise above the feudal class of peasant.

Comment: So, to be clear, does this mean that Makans lived better, or the same as the other peasants?

Comment: @Milkyway As the answer says, the degree is unknown. You can consider *favourable* to be synonymous with *positive* or *amenable*.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be read as

"*One can compare Makan's quality of life as **being** favourable **in comparison** to that of most other peasants in regions.*"

Or understood as "One can compare Makan's quality of life **as one that would be favoured by most people over the quality of life of** most other peasants in regions.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that deciding which has a better quality of life, Makan or most of the other peasants, would depend on how you compare them.

Read as:

*It is possible to make the comparison in such a way that Makan's quality of life seems better than that of most other peasants in the region.*

Would everyone come to this conclusion? No. It all depends on how you make the comparison.